# what's wrong with syntax in my query?

Tags: java, mysql

```
query = "update transaksi set cloth = '"+txtCloth.getText()+"', quantity = '"+txtQty.getText()+"', price = '"+txtPrice.getText()+"', total = '"+txtTotal.getText()+"', pay = '"+txtPay.getText()+"', change = '"+txtChange.getText()+"' where id = "+txtId.getText();
```

It says

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error
>   in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL
>   server version for the right syntax to use near `'change = '64' where id = 9'` at line 1

Comment: the query is working if i delete change = '"+txtChange.getText()+"'

Comment: try this 
 query = "update transaksi set cloth = '"+txtCloth.getText()+"', " +
            "quantity = '"+txtQty.getText()+"', price = '"+txtPrice.getText()+"'," +
            "total = '"+txtTotal.getText()+"', pay = '"+txtPay.getText()+"', change = '"+txtChange.getText()+"' where id = '"+txtId.getText()+"'"

Comment: thanks, but i just fixed it hahaha

Comment: nice to know that you have found the error and fixed by yourself..

Comment: @davidOnly use prepared statements. Its much more readable and secure.

Comment: @davidOnly you can describe your answer below. by that if any other people come across the same problem then can follow your answer. :)

Comment: i just change the column name in the table and everything connect to that column. and it works. not sure why the name "change" dont work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just change the column name in the table and everything connect to that column. and it works. not sure why the name "change" dont work

Comment: It did not work because the word `CHANGE` is reserved for MySQL internal use. Read [*Reserved Words in MySQL 5.6*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-6.html). Though there is a workaround to use such reserved words as database object names, it is suggested to use some other appropriate names.

Answer (score 0):

Use Of `PreparedStatement` will help  you in not creating this mess

**Try this :**

```
String query = "update transaksi set cloth = ?, quantity = ?, price = ?, total = ?, pay = ?, change = ? where id = ?";

PreparedStatement preparedStatement =
        connection.prepareStatement(query);

preparedStatement.setString(1, txtCloth.getText());
preparedStatement.setString(2, txtQty.getText());
preparedStatement.setString (3, txtPrice.getText());
..................................................//and so on
ResultSet result = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
```